# Clean/idiomatic/concise way to return an Option from a map in Scala

Tags: scala

In the following code is there an inline way to return either the first value or None?  Handling of Options has seemed more verbose than anticipated.

```
def findBySqlName(sqlName : String) = {
  map.iterator.find{ case (cname, col) =>
    col.sqlName == sqlName
  }.someThingInlineHereThatReturnsTheFirstValueOrNoneIfEmpty
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just map.find?

```
val map = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")

def findByValue(v: String) = map.find(_._2 == v)

println(findByValue("a"))
println(findByValue("c"))
```

In your case to get value:

```
def findBySqlName(sqlName : String) = {
  map.iterator.find{ case (cname, col) =>
    col.sqlName == sqlName
  }.map(_._2)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but in you can use `collectFirst` to do `find` and `map` in one step:

```
def findBySqlName(sqlName : String) = {
  map.collectFirst({ case (cname, col) if (col.sqlName == sqlName) => col._2 })
}
```

Comment: Yes I like this, will add to toolbox.